# Cordova emulate android Exit Code 1

Tags: android, cordova

I have code that is building successfully through cordova. However, when I try to emulate it, I get this error "Error:cmd: Command failed with exit code 1". Any ideas on how to fix this?[Here is my output from attempting to emulate the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LqiN.png)

Comment: please run with `--verbose` and post additional output

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a tour [How do I ask a good question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: what plugins are you using?

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem. It looks like you don't have any AVD running. I don't think ionic's tutorial specifies that you need to do that. I assume you're following [this](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/installation.html) guide.

To fix the issue (if the error in your case is also caused by the lack of Android Virtual Device running) simply:

1. Start Android Studio.
2. Navigate to Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager.
3. Create virtual device (button on the bottom left corner).
4. Set up the device by configuring it to suit your needs.
5. Run the virtual device by pushing the green triangle in AVD Manager, under "Actions" column (a new window with the emulated phone should pop up).
6. Run the `ionic emulate android` command again.

Note that if you - for some reason - don't have "Android" submenu under "Tools" menu (that was my first issue), you have to simply start the Android Studio installer once more and reinstall it, making sure you check the box for Android Virtual Device during installation.

Comment: Make sure your cordova version supports the SDK version that your emulator device supports.

Comment: First clicking "play" in Android Studio AVD to start the emulator then running my `npm start:android` command is what fixed things for me

Answer (score 0):

I Had this issue, it was because I hadn't my install of  [HAXM](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/android-studio/haxm-installation-failed-install-intel-haxm-in-windows/) was failing. This is I guess because I needed to restart my machine or because I hadn't enabled Hyper-v Platform (NOT MANAGER THOUGH)

[image]

I enabled Hyper-VP Platform, restarted, and all was well :)