# An error occurred while running cordova emulate android (exit code 1)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, emulation

when I tried to connect to emulator with ionic I get two errors.
An error occurred while running cordova emulate android (exit code 1)
You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

In the answer in this link, "Set up the device by configuring it to suit your needs" but I couldn't understand how can I set up and how I know my needs.

[Cordova emulate android Exit Code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43121016/cordova-emulate-android-exit-code-1)